# Coming from MODO - why is X mirror not selecting the other side of this disconnected geo?

Tags: modeling

My first post, i'm totally new to blender, SLOWLY leaving modo.

First question.

I selected the faces on the left side and nothing selects on the right side. i'm GUESSING it's because the mesh is broken up? In modo it does not work this way. Please tell me i can still select stuff with symmetry even though the mesh is several meshes? I'm totally stuck. really appreciate any info on this.

Cheers

[image]

Comment: x-mirror does not mirror selections, but it mirrors the transformations you do

Comment: You could delete all mesh on one side, then add a mirror modifier by going to the properties panel on the right, under the modifiers tab.  This makes it so that you have one side to work with, and the other side is created by the modifier.  This means that when you select mesh on one side, it is essentially selected on the other side.  Try it out, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Thank you guys for your replies. A friend from work who knows a bit more about blender showed me today that the geo on the other side IS actually being affected, but the selection does not show up on screen? I find that confusing as it's so easy to break symmetry. i like seeing my selection on the mirrored axis so i know symmetry is working. so...yeah, seems like this does work, just no selection mirroring as well? I'd like to request this as a feature somehow?